# Finding substring in RegEx Java

Tags: java, regex

Hello I have a question about RegEx. I am currently trying to find a way to grab a substring of any letter followed by any two numbers such as: d09.

I came up with the RegEx `^[a-z]{1}[0-9]{2}$` and ran it on the string

> sedfdhajkldsfakdsakvsdfasdfr30.reed.op.1xp0

However, it never finds r30, the code below shows my approach in Java.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-z]{1}[0-9]{2}$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("sedfdhajkldsfakdsakvsdfasdfr30.reed.op.1xp0");

if(matcher.matches())
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

it never prints out anything because matcher never finds the substring (when I run it through the debugger), what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three errors:

1. Your expression contains [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html). `^` matches only at the start of the string, and `$` only matches at the end. So your regular expression will match `"r30"` but not `"foo_r30_bar"`. You are searching for a substring so you should remove the anchors.
2. The `matches` should be `find`.
3. You don't have a group 1 because you have no parentheses in your regular expression. Use `group()` instead of `group(1)`.

Try this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-z][0-9]{2}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("sedfdhajkldsfakdsakvsdfasdfr30.reed.op.1xp0");

if(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());    
}
```

[ideone](http://ideone.com/MPI7Br)

---

[**Matcher Documentation**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)

> A matcher is created from a pattern by invoking the pattern's matcher method. Once created, a matcher can be used to perform three different kinds of match operations:
>
> - The matches method attempts to match the entire input sequence against the pattern.
> - The lookingAt method attempts to match the input sequence, starting at the beginning, against the pattern.
> - The find method scans the input sequence looking for the next subsequence that matches the pattern.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't match because `^` and `$` delimite the start and the end of the string. If you want it to be anywhere, remove that and you will succed.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your regex is anchored, as such it will never match unless the whole input matches your regex. Use `[a-z][0-9]{2}`.
2. Don't use `.matches()` but `.find()`: `.matches()` is shamefully misnamed and tries to match the whole input.

Answer (score 0):

How about `"[a-z][0-9][0-9]"`? That should find all of the substrings that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

> ^[a-z]{1}[0-9]{2}$
>
> sedfdhajkldsfakdsakvsdfasdfr30.reed.op.1xp0

as far as i can read this

- find thr first lower *gives*[s] caps letter after it there should be two numbers meaning the length of your string is and always will be 3 word chars

Maybe if i have more data about your string  i can help

**EDIT**

if you are sure of *number of dots then

change this line

```
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("sedfdhajkldsfakdsakvsdfasdfr30.reed.op.1xp0");
```

to

```
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("sedfdhajkldsfakdsakvsdfasdfr30.reed.op.1xp0".split("\.")[0]);
```

note:-

using my solution you should omit the leading ^ for pattern

read this page for [Spliting strings](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Ehasti/cs302/examples/Parsing/parseString.html)